# Nice way to print out records

Tags: java, parsing

I'm writing a file translator for my company that grabs data from a source file and writes a bunch of delimited records to a target file.  The records have the form:

HEADER*REC 1*REC 2*REC 3*REC 4

If a record is empty, and there is another record that can come after it, then the value is not printed, but the delimiter is included, e.g.:

HEADER*REC 1**REC 3*REC 4

If a record is empty, and it is the last record in the series, then the value and the delimiter are omitted, e.g.:

HEADER*REC 1*REC 2*REC 3

I was trying to think of a nice way to describe this in code, other than (pseudocode):

```
if last record is empty
    print this
otherwise
    print this other thing
```

I guess the code isn't too ugly, but I'd like a nicer solution.  I'm using a StringBuilder to write the data for each transaction (each set of records corresponds to a transaction, so I can iterate through a TransactionSet Object.), and if I can, I try to avoid copious switch/if statements.  If anyone knows of a more nicer, or elegant way to do this I would love to hear it.

EDIT: Clarified block of pseudocode

Comment: `print this == print this` so no need for any condition :D

Comment: not to pick - but this sounds like it should be XML instead.  then you could use all the prebuilt XML writing and parsing tools...

Comment: XML would be good, but there's some error checking that I need to do before/during translation which made Java seem like a better choice.

Comment: This sound a lot like CSV (comma separated values) but with `*`. There are some libraries there to format in CSV (it is not a simple as it seems) and by using them you will avoid issues that you still have not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
System.out.print("HEADER");
StringBuilder sep = new StringBuilder();
for(String rec: headings) {
   sep.append("*");
   if(rec != null && !rec.isEmpty()) {
      System.out.print(sep + rec);
      sep.setLength(0);
   }
}
System.out.println();
```

This way it will only print a "*" if you have a heading to come after it.

Comment: I think that would fail if the record is empty, and It occurs in the middle somewhere.  I want an empty record in the middle to just be two delimiters next to each other (**).

Comment: So you want empty records to appear as empty records, unless they appear at the end?

Comment: That works well, I didn't think of using a temp StringBuilder before, thanks!